# Using awk to sort fields and arrange

Tags: awk

Im trying to learn awk at the moment and I want to do a specific task. My question is similar in scope to one previously posted([Using awk to transpose column to row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634816/using-awk-to-transpose-column-to-row)), but wouldn't quite work for my data. I have been trying to work out why and im sure its quite simple.

I have large data in a tab delimited table with only two fields (example below):

```
1101\t7778
1101\t7755
1101\t8889
1101\t6789
2300\t1220
4000\t2333
4000\t7555
4000\t9000
4000\t1111
```

and I want to end up appending the second field onto a row when the field matches. The desired output would be:

```
1101\t7778\t7755\t8889\t6789
2300\t1220
4000\t2333\t7555\t9000\t1111
```

If possible, Id like to get an explaination of all the parts within the command so I can understand it in the future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well +1 for anyone who gives a pure bash solution :)

Comment: @abasu: See bellow... ;)

Comment: @gammyknee: And the Oscar goes to...?

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '    { list[$1] = list[$1] "\t" $2 }
     END { for (i in list) printf "%s%s\n", i, list[i] }' data
```

The first line adds a tab and the second field to the `list` element indexed by `$1`.  The second line prints out the key and the accumulated list of values.

Sample output:

```
1101    7778    7755    8889    6789
4000    2333    7555    9000    1111
2300    1220
```

If you want the first column sorted, you can pipe the output through `sort -n`.  If you have GNU `awk`, you can investigate the built-in sort function too:

```
/usr/gnu/bin/awk '    { list[$1] = list[$1] "\t" $2 }
                  END { n = asorti(list, indexes);
                        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                            printf "%s%s\n", indexes[i], list[indexes[i]]
                      }' data
```

Sorted output:

```
1101    7778    7755    8889    6789
2300    1220
4000    2333    7555    9000    1111
```

Comment: Excellent thanks! Would there be any conflict with different characters? Using the numerical data this answer worked perfectly, but with some other characters the solution doesn't work.  for eg:     PAK_74_MK_1st_fwd\tPBK_85_MK_2nd_RC
    PAK_74_MK_1st_fwd\tPBK_124_MK_2nd_RC
    PAK_74_MK_1st_fwd\tPBK_94_MK_2nd_RC
    PAK_74_MK_1st_fwd\tPBK_150_MK_2nd_RC
    PAK_75_MK_1st_fwd\tPBK_128_MK_2nd_RC
    PAK_75_MK_1st_fwd\tPBK_134_MK_2nd_RC
    PAK_75_MK_1st_fwd\tPBK_139_MK_2nd_RC
    PAK_75_MK_1st_fwd\tPBK_69_MK_2nd_RC
Is there any reason why it won't work?

Comment: Actually that works anyway. Must be a dodgey character later on in the file. Thanks for the explanation about the awk command :)

Comment: It should be fine with a fairly varied range of inputs.  It splits on white space (arbitrary sequences of blanks and tabs); it does not require the key values in any specific order, nor all the entries for a given key to appear on adjacent lines.  If something contained two values for one key, then you'd need to iterate on `NF` (the number of fields) in the accumulate line.  If you needed to sort the values for a key, that would require extra processing.  About the only thing that would stop it 'working' is an actual backslash lower-case 't' sequence in the data.

Answer (score 3):

For abasu's request a pure `bash` version:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash
while read x y; do
  hash[$x]=${hash[$x]}"\t"$y
done <<XXX
1101    7778
1101    7755
1101    8889
1101    6789
2300    1220
4000    2333
4000    7555
4000    9000
4000    1111
XXX

for i in ${!hash[*]}; { echo -e $i${hash[$i]};}
```

Output:

```
2300    1220
1101    7778    7755    8889    6789
4000    2333    7555    9000    1111
```

In the here-is-the-document there is a tab character between the columns, as well as in between the output columns. If the `-e` is removed from the last line after `echo` the output is:

```
2300\t1220
1101\t7778\t7755\t8889\t6789
4000\t2333\t7555\t9000\t1111
```

Comment: awesome :) nice solution, without any external tool

Comment: thats nothing, if you make the last line as `for i in ${!hash[*]}; { echo $i${hash[$i]};} | sort` it will give a sorted output

Comment: @abasu: Unfortunately `sort` is not a `bash` internal command so using it would not be a pure `bash` solution! The `sort` functionality should be programmed as a `bash` function, but I skip it now. :)

Comment: true, I missed the point, `sort` makes it a non-pure bash solution.

Answer (score 3):

This version does not end up storing the whole file in memory. Neither does it rearrange the order of the keys.

```
awk -F '\t' '
    $1 != prev {
        if (prev) print ""
        printf "%s", $1
        prev=$1
    }
    {printf "%s%s", FS, $2}
    END {print ""}
' f
```

```
1101    7778    7755    8889    6789
2300    1220
4000    2333    7555    9000    1111
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from [Kent's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743906/970195) answer.

```
awk '{
         a[$1]=a[$1] ? a[$1] FS $2 : $2
    } 
END {
        for (key in a) print key,a[key]
    }' FS='\t' OFS='\t' f
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pure `bash` implementation just for fun, uses string slicing instead of regexps assuming 4 digit numbers only, so it's not robust, but the version of `bash` I'm working with doesn't have built-in regexp so I was at a loss as to what else I could do!

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
        array[${line:0:4}]="${array[${line:0:4}]}${line:4:8}"
        indicies[${line:0:4}]=${line:0:4}

done < $1

for i in ${indicies[@]}; do
        echo "$i${array[$i]}"
done
```